# Updating record without using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with editing a record on the view page; I get the edit page but the records are not in the field. I'm not sure after I find the id; how do I get the records from the view

View

```
<h4>Student</h4>
<hr />
<div class="form-group">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-m2-1">Student Number</th>
            <th class="col-md-2"> Name</th>
        </tr>
        if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var issueditem in @Model.items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2">@item.studentNumber</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">@item.Name</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.lineNum }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = item.lineNum }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item?');" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    IssueDAO dbData = new IssueDAO();

    Item item = new Item();

    return View(dbData.GetStudent().Find(smodel => smodel.id == id));
}
```

Method

```
public List<StudentModel> GetStudent()
{
    connection();

    List<StudentModel> studentlist = new List<StudentModel>();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetStudentDetails", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    con.Open();
    sd.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
         studentlist.Add(new StudentModel
                             {
                                 Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]),
                                 Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"])
                             });
    }

    return studentlist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs to have the `model` directive.

`@model StudentModel`

This will ensure that Razor can bind `@Model` to whatever type you are returning from your controller.

Something else that will end up being a problem with the code snippet that you shared:

```
//references to @item should be @issueditem or this code will fail.
foreach (var issueditem in @Model.items)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.studentNumber</td> //@item should be @issueditem
        <td class="col-md-2">@issueditem.Name</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = issueditem.lineNum }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = issueditem.lineNum }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item?');" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please change code as per your requirement , below code is for reference purpose.**

Step 1 : First of all create view for **Edit** Method.

```
    @model StudentModel; //Give reference model as per your code

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Controller Name", "Update", FormMethod.Post))
    {

<h4>Form Title</h4>
<hr />

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Change password" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Step 2 : Add below Method in Controller

```
    public ActionResult Update(StudentModel stuModel)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Procedure";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stuModel.Id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stuModel.Name;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblMessage.Text = "Record updated successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Step 3 : Please use **firstorDefault** Method to find object for model see below.

```
       public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        IssueDAO dbData = new IssueDAO();

        Item item = new Item();

        //Model is same type which you passed in Edit View => StudentModel
        var Model = dbData.Students
                   .where(s => s.id == id)
                   .FirstOrDefault<StudentModel>();

        return View(Model); 
    }
```

Comment: So what does dbData.Students relate to? or it should be Update

Comment: dbData.Students related to Database. dbData  is context and In this code we selected students entity where id is equal to whatever come from edit view.

Comment: FirstorDefault method is for select single and first object from entity.

Comment: For Calling Update Method - that wrote in form post method , you can see there                                                                                          
@using (Html.BeginForm("Controller Name", "Update", FormMethod.Post))
    {

Comment: I tried this method but there was no student record in the fields

Comment: there's no method in dbData about Students

Comment: Refresh your EDMX Object or Check your EDMX is there any Entity like Students And If you are not use EDMX then , you need to write select Query for getting student data.